# Rails 5 data-method=delete sends GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem setting my http verb to delete.  This is my first app in rails 5 and I'm also using a purchased theme so I am sure I'm missing something stupid.  When I create the link below:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

I get

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Sign out</a>
```

however this is still sending a GET request.  Most of the answers I've seen say to check if jquery ujs is getting loaded.  It looks like it is.  Am I missing anything else?

```
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-e87806d0cf4489aeb1bb7288016024e8de67fd18db693fe026fe3907581e53cd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

Comment: Is jquery (not ujs) loaded too? Do you have any errors in browser console? Is JavaScript enabled in your browser? Anyway data-method="delete" should create shadow form and emulate delete with it (if browser supports it). You can use button_to too.

Comment: Sergey - jquery also gets loaded and js is not disabled.  I'm able to use jQuery selectors in the browser console.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: You can try to find e.stopPropagation() in your javaScript, or try therubyracer gem instead of execjs, or try to disable turbolinks may be...

Comment: Sergey thanks for your tips.  I dug through the theme js files and commented out $account_menu.click(function (e) { e.stopPropagation() }); and it looks like this link is working.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem.
what i did:
run  delete all compiled assets

`rails assets:clobber`

change config/production.rb

`config.assets.compile = true`

application.js:

```
//= require jquery2
//= require jquery_ujs
```

hope it helps