# Ruby on Rails 5, Rspec 3.8, test environment destroy function acts as the show function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, puma

I am following the [restaurantly](http://rubyonrailstutor.github.io/) Rails tutorial while making my own changes whenever I run into version (mostly syntax) issues between Rails version 4 and the Rails version 5 that I am using.

After completing the steps through [this](http://rubyonrailstutor.github.io/editupdateintegration/restaurants-edit-update-integration/) page on the tutorial I thought it was another syntax difference after my test failed for the destroy function.

```
rspec spec/features/restaurants_spec.rb

Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 3.12.0 , codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:41471
.F

Failures:

  1) destroy links work displays Restaurantly Spots!
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_no_content 'mc ruby'
       expected not to find text "mc ruby" in "mc ruby"
     # ./spec/features/restaurants_spec.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 7.25 seconds (files took 2.24 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/restaurants_spec.rb:20 # destroy links work displays Restaurantly Spots!
```

I ran `puma -e 'test'` to manually run the application in the "test" environment and in the browser step through the controller actions myself. I found that I got the same failed behaviour. All my defined actions including, `create`, `edit`, `update`, and `show` worked as expected. However `destroy` acted like `show` and simply displayed the show page for the item instead or redirecting to the root and deleting the item.

This all works as expected if I run `rails server` in the "development" environment including the `destroy` function.

Here are some different parts of my application in case it helps:

```
app/controllers/restaurants_controller.rb:



    def destroy
        @restaurant = Restaurant.find_by_id params[:id]
        @restaurant.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
      end
```

---

```
app/views/restaurants/index.html.haml

.row
  .large-8.columns.large-centered
  %h3.subheader.center
    Restaurantly Spots!

.row
  .large-8-columns.large-centered
    - @restaurants.each do |restaurant|
      %h5.subheader
        = restaurant.name
        = link_to "edit", edit_restaurant_path(restaurant)
        = link_to "destroy", restaurant_path(restaurant), method: :destroy
```

---

Part of my Gemfile that including the the development, test gems:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
end
```

I dropped the test database at one point and then created it again. I did this the same way I created it originally along with the development database by running `bundle exec rake db:create`, then `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and lastly `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare`.

```
config/database.yml

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: restaurantly_dev
  pool: 5
  host: ""
  timeout: 5432


test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: restaurantly_test
  pool: 5
  host: ""
  timeout: 5432
```

Any ideas why it behaves differently for just the destroy function between the development and the test environment?

Comment: What does the test look like? Also, `method` should be `:delete` not `:destroy` (it's the name of the REST request METHOD (GET POST DELETE PATCH etc), not the method/action name. And also, Rails uses javascript to turn links with `method: :delete` in DELETE requests, so a link to delete won't work if you don't support javascript on your test driver.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @arieljuod for pointing out that I had the method as `:destroy` when it should have been `:delete`. I may have added that by accident during my troubleshooting so I can't say that was the issue all along. Especially because the delete function was working in the development environment and not the test environment. However I was then getting a routing error after I made the change which I had not seen before and it was still trying to `POST` instead of `DELETE`.

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678865/rails-5-data-method-delete-sends-get-request) and found that after removing //= require jquery2
`and`//= require jquery_ujs`from the`application.css` file that all seemed to be working fine in both production and test. I don't know why those were there or why it corrected the issue. My feature tests now pass as well.